# How do I view test results on a per test iteration basis?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to view a bar graph of test results for each iteration on a per test basis?

For example, I have a Test Suite with 5 Test Cases. Each Test Case has 44 iterations. I would like to be able to generate a graph of the results of the iterations.
[Graph Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuD1f.png)

Alternatively, if that is not possible, is it possible to generate a graph with the iteration results as the counts instead of the test results?
[Graph Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luz8K.png)

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these two question , I am afraid it is not possible in Azure Devops. Currently, Azure Devops does not provide out of the box charts for test case iterations and does not provide the API to get test cases iterations .

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions.

[image]

After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Comment: It is sad to hear that there is no solution to this issue. I will think of possible ways I can adjust my test cases to accommodate for this. I will also try talking to our company's local Microsoft Azure Dev Ops rep for further suggestions. Thank you.